# Define function as list element

Tags: python

```
>>> list=[None]
>>> def list[0](x,y):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def list[0](x,y):
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I define a function as an element of a list?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I think what you want is something you shouldn't do, but even then I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: I am quite impressed why so many users downvote this legit question.

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question.  Some other languages do allow generic lvalues (not just identifiers) as a target for a function definition.  The OP reasonably thought Python might support similar flexibility in function definition targets.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: What languages allow that? I know Lua allows defining things like `a.b`, but I don't know any that would allow defining something like `(a + b)(c)[d]`.

Comment: @Hyperboreus I agree with you.  It seems many of the python followers recently like to downvote questions made by people that don't understand basic python syntax.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I strongly suspect that the OP is in the process of reinventing object-oriented programming, poorly.

Comment: @Hyperboreus I'm rather impressed that so many people _upvoted_ the question. As Seth said, people who don't get the basics, ask a very confused and vague question and, most importantly, don't show any effort (even if it is just "I googled for [whatever] but couldn't find anything", "I read a tutorial here but didn't understand"), get downvoted - and this is a _good_ thing because not doing research shouldn't be encouraged. If a question can be solved by pointing to the most basic of language rules, I will downvote unless OP gives me a good reason not to do so.

Comment: Treating functions as r-values, or treating elemenst of a list as l-values has IMHO nothing to do with reinventing OO. Poorly.

Comment: After all, it is just syntactical sugar he got wrong. `l [0] = lambda x: whatEverYouWantToDo (x)`.

Comment: @l4mpi For the record, I was saying I'm discouraged by the downvoting of people who don't fully understand the language yet.  This isn't just a Q&A for experts.  Everyone needs help sometimes, and not everyone can self teach themselves from online resources.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python's `def` isn't flexible enough to handle generic [lvalues](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lvalue) such as `list[0]`.  The language only allows you to use an *identifier* as function name.  Here are the relevant parts of the [grammar rule for the def-statement](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

```
funcdef        ::=  "def" funcname "(" [parameter_list] ")" ":" suite
funcname       ::=  identifier
```

Instead, you can use a series of assignment and definition statements:

```
s = [None]

def f(x, y):
    return x + y

s[0] = f
```

As an alternative, you could also store a [`lambda` expression](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lambda) directly in a list:

```
s = [lambda x,y : x+y]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
def f(whatever):
    do_stuff()

l[0] = f
```

The function definition syntax doesn't allow you to define a function directly into a data structure, but you can just create the function and then assign it wherever it needs to go.

Comment: Or `l = []; l.append(f)`

Comment: @SethMMorton: Or just `l = [f]` if you're controlling the creation of `l` instead of trying to assign the function into an existing spot, but I figured this would be clearer.

Answer (score 4):

```
def someFunctionA(x, y):
    return x+y

def someFunctionB(x, y):
    return x*y

someList = [someFunctionA, someFunctionB]

print someList[0](2, 3)
print someList[1](5, 5)
```

Comment: Why not `l = [someFunctionA, someFunctionB]`? (Besides, it is better not to use `list` as an identifier.)

Comment: I did that first, but got an error and thought lambda was necessary. It works now however so obviously lambda was redundant. +1!

Comment: I think the complaint about using `list` as an identifier stands.  Shadowing `list` is not good.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing such a freedom would make parsing harder... for example the parenthesized expression

```
...(x, y, z=3)
```

can be either a parameter declaration (where `3` is the default for keyword parameter z) or a call (that is passing `z` keyword parameter value as `3`).

If you want to allow a generic assignable expression in `def` you also need to allow

```
def foo(x, y, z=3)[3](x, y, z=3):
    ...
```

where the first parenthesized part has a different semantic meaning and syntax rules from the second part.

Writing a parser for this is annoying (basically because you need to process an arbitrary unbounded amount of source code without understanding it) and is what for example lead to the worst parsing rule in the whole universe I know (it's the dreaded [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) of C++) that basically just gave up on trying to get a decent language by resigning to ambiguity.

Note that in many cases when it's harder for a program to do the parsing it's because of ambiguity that would make also harder for a human to understand it.

Python correctly values readability as very important.

Functions in Python are however first class objects so you can solve your problem easily enough:

```
def foo(...):
    ...

mylist[index] = foo
```

or, only if the function is a single expression, with

```
mylist[index] = lambda ... : ...
```

(but `lambda` is very limited, both because it's sort of "hated" in the Python community and also because it would create some annoyance at the syntax level because of the need of handling indentation inside parenthesis).

Note also that something that a few Python novices don't know is that you can use `def` even inside a function; for example:

```
def register_http():
    def handle_http(connection):
        ...
    global_register['http'] = handle_http
```

that will assign a function as element of a global map without polluting the global (module) namespace with its name. A local `def` can also create a closure by capturing local state variables (read-only in 2.x or even read/write in 3.x).

Note also that if you need some processing of a function may be `decorators` can be useful. For example by defining

```
def register(name):
    def do_registering(f):
        global_register[name] = f
        return f
    return do_registering
```

you can just use

```
@register('http')
def handle_http(connection):
    ...
```

Comment: You are completely right, but alas I have to rant about the fact that such a complicated thing is needed. There is a very nice syntax element: decorators. They could easily used for that. What I sometimes do is to return or yield a function, but decorators don't work for statements. `@return` or `@yield` would be quite nice, however. In this case here, we could have a `@=target` (would be ugly because of the assign target being on the right) or maybe `@@target`, such as `@@global_register['http']` before the function, removing the need for ugly assignment/yield/return line after the function.

Comment: @glglgl: you can do something simpler than that using parametric decorators like `@register('http')`. They're sort of strange to implement (a parametric decorator must return an un-parametric decorator function) but they're nice to use. See edit.

Comment: Right, that is a nice alternative in this case; I forgot about that. But, alas, not usable for simplifying things like `yield` or `return`.